# Error on magento 2 DB import

Tags: magento2, database

I've created a magento 2.3.2 that works locally on pc (using laragon, if it matters). Now I need to transfer site to working server, so I made a backup using phpmyadmin and tried to import .sql file into server.

I edited file to use correct database on server, as well as user that has privileges on server. User on local machine is root. User on server is an user in a shared environment.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`SHARED_USERNAME_IN_SERVER`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS
SELECT DISTINCT `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
    `product`.`sku` AS `sku`
FROM (`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
JOIN `catalog_product_entity` `product` ON `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)
```

Problem is I get:

> MySQL: #1227 - “Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation”

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: either you need to create a definer `SHARED_USERNAME_IN_SERVER` in your PhpMyAdmin Or replace `SHARED_USERNAME_IN_SERVER` with `root` in database file and import.

Comment: @Pawan I tried to use "root" instead of SHARED_USERNAME_IN_SERVER, however got same result. I don't have root access on server.

Comment: if you do not have access to `root`, you can use database user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it working by changing definer to DEFINER=CURRENT_USER:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=CURRENT_USER SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1`  AS  select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,`product`.`sku` AS `sku` from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)))
```

Answer (score 8):

Please run the following command then it imports normally.

```
sed -i 's|DEFINER=[^*]*\*|\*|g' [PATH/]dbdump.sql
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it didn't help, got: sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated `s' command

Comment: perfect solution @chirag working for me... thank you

Answer (score 4):

Try this command

```
sed -E 's/DEFINER=`[^`]+`@`[^`]+`/DEFINER=CURRENT_USER/g' nameOfYourDump.sql > nameOfYourDumpClean.sql
```

It will fix the file and write it under **nameOfYourDumpClean.sql**